# Adding options to mdbootstrap javascript alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Basic example of Bootstrap alert here.

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="alert-target" >Click me!</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#alert-target").click(function () {
    toastr["info"]("I was launched via jQuery!")
});
```

How do I add these Options to javascript?

Is this what makes my alerts not to show?

```
toastr.options = {
    "closeButton": true, // true/false
    "debug": false, // true/false
    "newestOnTop": false, // true/false
    "progressBar": false, // true/false
    "positionClass": "toast-top-right", // toast-top-right / toast-top-left / toast-bottom-right / toast-bottom-left
    "preventDuplicates": false, true/false
    "onclick": null,
    "showDuration": "300", // in milliseconds
    "hideDuration": "1000", // in milliseconds
    "timeOut": "5000", // in milliseconds
    "extendedTimeOut": "1000", // in milliseconds
    "showEasing": "swing",
    "hideEasing": "linear",
    "showMethod": "fadeIn",
    "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
}
```

Reference | https://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/alerts/

**FYI :** I can't upload external resource link, because it only exists in mdbootstrap download. that is why i am not able to a create JSFiddle demonstration.